# Problem with Assimp 3D model loader

Tags: c++, opengl, models, matrix, assimp

In my game I have model loading functions for Assimp model loading library. I can load the model and render it, but the model displays incorrectly. The models load in as if they were using a seperate projection matrix. I have looked over my code over and over again, but I probably keep on missing the obvious reason why this is happening.

Here is an image of my game:
[image: Misshaped cube]

It's simply a 6 sided cube, but it's off big time!

Here are my code snippets for rendering the cube to the screen:

```
void C_MediaLoader::display(void)
{
    float tmp;

    glTranslatef(0,0,0);
    // rotate it around the y axis
    glRotatef(angle,0.f,0.f,1.f);
    glColor4f(1,1,1,1);

    // scale the whole asset to fit into our view frustum 
    tmp = scene_max.x-scene_min.x;
    tmp = aisgl_max(scene_max.y - scene_min.y,tmp);
    tmp = aisgl_max(scene_max.z - scene_min.z,tmp);
    tmp = (1.f / tmp);
    glScalef(tmp/5, tmp/5, tmp/5);

    // center the model
    //glTranslatef( -scene_center.x, -scene_center.y, -scene_center.z );
    // if the display list has not been made yet, create a new one and
    // fill it with scene contents
    if(scene_list == 0) {
        scene_list = glGenLists(1);
        glNewList(scene_list, GL_COMPILE);
            // now begin at the root node of the imported data and traverse
            // the scenegraph by multiplying subsequent local transforms
            // together on GL's matrix stack.
        recursive_render(scene, scene->mRootNode);
        glEndList();
    }
    glCallList(scene_list);
}



void C_MediaLoader::recursive_render (const struct aiScene *sc, const struct aiNode* nd)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int n = 0, t;
    struct aiMatrix4x4 m = nd->mTransformation;

    // update transform
    aiTransposeMatrix4(&m);
    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrixf((float*)&m);

    // draw all meshes assigned to this node
    for (; n < nd->mNumMeshes; ++n) {
        const struct aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[nd->mMeshes[n]];

        apply_material(sc->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex]);

        if(mesh->mNormals == NULL) {
            glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
        } else {
            glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        }

        for (t = 0; t < mesh->mNumFaces; ++t) {
            const struct aiFace* face = &mesh->mFaces[t];
            GLenum face_mode;

            switch(face->mNumIndices) {
                case 1: face_mode = GL_POINTS; break;
                case 2: face_mode = GL_LINES; break;
                case 3: face_mode = GL_TRIANGLES; break;
                default: face_mode = GL_POLYGON; break;
            }

            glBegin(face_mode);

            for(i = 0; i < face->mNumIndices; i++) {
                int index = face->mIndices[i];

                if(mesh->mColors[0] != NULL)
                    glColor4fv((GLfloat*)&mesh->mColors[0][index]);

                if(mesh->mNormals != NULL) 
                    glNormal3fv(&mesh->mNormals[index].x);

                glVertex3fv(&mesh->mVertices[index].x);
            }

            glEnd();
        }
    }
    // draw all children
    for (n = 0; n < nd->mNumChildren; ++n) {
        recursive_render(sc, nd->mChildren[n]);
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Sorry there is so much code to look through, but I really cannot find the problem, and I would love to have help.

Comment: Debug it, make sure it's using the correct `face_mode` and check to make sure all the indices are getting added.

Comment: I've already done that, in ANY mode it has the exact same effect as seen in the image.

Comment: Really. If `face_mode` is set to `GL_POINTS`, it shows a deformed cube the the one you have in your image?

Comment: not exactly, but it does the same thing, where it is smaller and get's larger the farther it is in the z axis

Comment: So looking really close at the image, it looks like a the cube has all it's sides, but the one closest to the camera is very, very small. Is that correct?

Comment: Do you see the same problem if using one of the glu primitives like glu cylinder or a hand-built cube hard coded?

Comment: Yes it has it's 6 faces, but it's all projected funny.
and no I don't see the same issue when hard coding cubes.

Comment: Have you looked at what `nd->mTransformation` is giving you? Try commenting out your `// update transform` lines. I'm going to sleep so tag-team Patrick :)

Comment: nd->mTransformation, gives me [1 0 0 0]
                              [0 1 0 0] 
                              [0 0 1 0]
                              [0 0 0 1]
and commenting out the three lines doesn't help or create more issues

Comment: Silly question but should not the face of a cube have 6 and not 3 here for mNumIndices?  switch(face->mNumIndices  case 3: face_mode = GL_TRIANGLES  assuming it's just a two-triangle quad, it's been ages since I've done anything with assimp.

Comment: a cube face if created with GL_TRIANGLES it would have 6 indicies

Comment: So the default: case that's switched on mNumIndices is defaulting to GL_POLYGON if your cube is actually two triangles?  What are the index and vertex counts, plus face mode when you glBegin()?

Comment: ok here is something interesting, Assimp is saying I have 12 faces, referring to triangles. I would expect you to be able to use GL_QUADS, but you can't in this situation. There are 36 indices, and 8 vertices. If it helps, Assimp is also outputting that it has, triangulated the polygons, so that's why they're in triangle form.

Comment: Triangles are cool, GL just turns quads into triangles behind your back anyways.  In this case I think that you want to force glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES).  Each face in your inner loop should show 3 indices that output 3 vertices for each begin/end pair.

Comment: ok it defaults to GL_TRIANGLES, anyway, but I set that to default because of the triangulization. there are 24 vertices and 36 indices. My last posting was wrong with the vertices, because I wasn't thinking correctly.

Comment: also, when I translate the cube after placing it, here is what I get... http://i1185.photobucket.com/albums/z357/BWebster890/viewport_problem2.png

Comment: It looks like you just have some really weird perspective going on. How are you setting up your view and projection matrices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with my perspective, I was able to solve my problem by setting the `gluPerspective` correctly:

```
void C_MediaLoader::display(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 640/480,
        1.0, 1000.0);  /* Znear and Zfar */

    // remainder code is the same as before...
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: You should post a little more detail about how you solved the problem instead of what you have here.

Comment: OK, I just added in the extra details

Comment: I edited your post to better reflect the answer. Remember to accept your answer when you're able.